# How to Specify what Data should be stored in a variable with Client & Server in C#?

Tags: c#, database, sockets

So, I am working on a Game that uses a Server. I am trying to add a username & password system, but have run into a issue. When I send the Data from the client to the server, the Server receives it, but I can't think of a system to specify what the data is and where is should be stored.

For example, say I send the Username from my Client to the Server. The Server receives it, but how can I let it know that it's a username, not a password?

If anyone can help, thank you.

Note: If it helps, I am using C# in Visual Studio.

***Server Code***

```
int recv; // Holds how much data we are reading
            byte[] data = new byte[1024]; // Byte Array of data, used for everything recived and sent to the server

            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 904); // Listener for connections

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp); // Stores connection from client
            socket.Bind(endpoint); // Bind incoming connection to socket

            Console.WriteLine(" >> Waiting for client...");

            IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 904); // Wait for connection, once recived, sets sender to connected IP
            EndPoint tmpRemote = (EndPoint)sender; // Stores client temp

            recv = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref tmpRemote); // Stores all client info, get data it's sending (And how much data is in it)

            Console.WriteLine(" >> Data received from {0}", tmpRemote.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv)); // Convert data into string and display it

            string welcome = " >> Welcome to AlphaNET!"; // Welcome Message
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome); // Convert Welcome to sendable bytes

            if (socket.Connected) //Checking if socket is still connected, if so, send welcome message
            {
                socket.Send(data); // Send welcome message
            }

            while (true) // Our loop to check for data, goes on forever
            {
                if (!socket.Connected) // Checks to see if client is not connected, if true, write to console and break the loop
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> Data Sent");
                }

                data = new byte[1024]; // Resets data var
                recv = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref tmpRemote);

                if (recv == 0) // If no info is recived, break loop
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            socket.Close();
```

***Client Code***

```
public void sendUsr()
    {
        String username = usrBox.Text;
        byte[] packetData =            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username); 
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp); // Makes socket to send data
        socket.SendTo(packetData, ep); // Sends data to server
    }
```

Comment: Depends completely how you're sending the data. You may want to look into data formats, such as XML, JSON, etc.

Comment: Guess sending the code could help, leme add it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rob said, you may want to format your data using data-interchange format, before you send them. I prefer use JSON provided by Newtonsoft.Json libary. You need to have a reference to it.

**Client Code**

```
String dataToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { username = usrBox.Text, password = pwdBox.Text });
```

**Server Code**

```
recv = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref tmpRemote); // Stores all client info, get data it's sending (And how much data is in it)   
dynamic receivedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
String username = (string)receivedData.username;
String password = (string)receivedData.password;
```

Comment: Anytime dude! Glad to help